# A basic doubt on ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE

$$x'(t) = h(x(t)), x(0) = \bar{x} $$

Consider two solutions of the ODE $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. Suppose $y(0)$ is attained by $x(t)$ for infinitely many values of $t$. Is it true that $y(t')$ is also attained by  the trajectory $x(.)$ infinitely many times for any $t'$ ? Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Consider the linear, homogeneous equation

$a y'' + b y' + c = 0$,

where $\Delta := b^2 - 4ac < 0$ and $\frac{b}{a} > 0$, defined on any half-infinite interval $(t_0, \infty)$, $t_0 < 0$, subject to the initial value condition $y(0) = 0$. The solutions are the functions

$y_{\lambda}(t) = \lambda e^{-b t / 2a} \sin (\sqrt{\Delta} t), \qquad t > t_0$,

where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. These functions obvious achieve the value $y_{\lambda}(0) = 0$ infinitely many times (at least whenever $t > t_0$ is an integer multiple of $d : =\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\Delta}}$). However, $|y_{\lambda}(t)| \leq |\lambda| e^{-b t / 2a}$, so by the Squeeze Theorem $\lim_{t \to +\infty} y_{\lambda} = 0$, and this together with the observation that the sign of $y_{\lambda}'$ changes precisely every $d$ units implies that $y_{\lambda}$ only assumes any given nonzero value finitely many times.